# my Django DayArchiveView is not detected in urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-views

I created several date-based views in Django, and while views for year and month function as expected, the view to display days is not detected. For instance, if I try to get `/balance/2018/`, or `/balance/2018/04/` the views will be displayed, while `/balance/2018/04/02` will fail. I understand that the problem must be with urls.py configuration, but I just cannot find it in documentation. I also tried passing day_format='%d' to as_view method, without any results.

my urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .views import ArticleYearArchiveView, ArticleMonthArchiveView, ArticleDayArchiveView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path(r'<int:year>/<int:month:>/<int:day>/', views.ArticleDayArchiveView.as_view(day_format='%d'), name='show_day'),
    path(r'<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.ArticleMonthArchiveView.as_view(month_format='%m'), name='show_month'),
    path(r'<int:year>/', views.ArticleYearArchiveView.as_view(), name='show_year'),
]
```

my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.dates import YearArchiveView, MonthArchiveView, DayArchiveView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db.models import Sum
from .models import Category, Article
import datetime
# Create your views here.

def index(request):

    num_of_articles = Article.objects.all().count()
    num_of_categories = Category.objects.all().count()
    return render(request, 'index.html', context = {
    'num_of_articles':num_of_articles,
    'num_of_categories':num_of_categories})

class ArticleYearArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    date_field = 'financial_day'
    make_object_list = True

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['summation'] = Article.objects.all().filter(financial_day__year=kwargs['year'].year).aggregate(Sum('amount_of_money'))['amount_of_money__sum']
        return context

class ArticleMonthArchiveView(MonthArchiveView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    date_field = 'financial_day'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['summation'] = Article.objects.all().filter(financial_day__year=kwargs['month'].year).filter(financial_day__month=kwargs['month'].month).aggregate(Sum('amount_of_money'))['amount_of_money__sum']
        return context


class ArticleDayArchiveView(DayArchiveView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    date_field = 'financial_day'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['summation'] = Article.objects.all().filter(financial_day__year=kwargs['day'].year).filter(financial_day__month=kwargs['day'].month).filter(financial_day__day=kwargs['day'].day).aggregate(Sum('amount_of_money'))['amount_of_money__sum']
        return context

#Here it'll show ARTICLE DETAILS for a given SLUG url
def show_article(request, article_slug):
    response = "You are looking at the article %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % article_slug)
```

Error text is:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/balance/2018/04/02

Using the URLconf defined in spendings_calculator.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    balance/ [name='index']
    balance/ <int:year>/<int:month:>/<int:day>/ [name='show_day']
    balance/ <int:year>/<int:month>/ [name='show_month']
    balance/ <int:year>/ [name='show_year']

The current path, balance/2018/04/02, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a stray `:` after month - `<int:month:>`. Remove it:

```
path(r'<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/', views.ArticleDayArchiveView.as_view(day_format='%d'), name='show_day'),
```

Also, note that you are defining the URL for `balance/2018/04/02/` (with a trailing slash) but you are going to `http://localhost:8000/balance/2018/04/02` (without a trailing slash). Once you have fixed the typo above, Django should redirect you to the URL with the trailing slash.

Comment: oh! thank you very much, I've re-read it a bunch of times and haven't seen it.